# I can't save data from ComboBox vb6

Tags: sql, sql-server, combobox, vb6

My `UserControl`:

[image]

All code from `UserControl`:

```
Option Explicit
Dim cnn As Connection
Dim indice As Integer

Public Property Get AddTypeID() As Integer
   AddTypeID = cmbAddExample(indice).ItemData(cmbAddExample(indice).ListIndex)
End Property

Public Property Let AddTypeID(ByVal Value As Integer)
   cmbAddExample(indice).ItemData(cmbAddExample(indice).ListIndex) = Value
End Property

Public Property Get AddType() As String
   AddType = cmbAddExample(indice).Text
End Property

Public Property Let AddType(ByVal Value As String)
   cmbAddExample(indice).Text = Value
End Property

Public Property Get AddNumber() As String
   AddNumber = Text1(indice).Text
End Property

Public Property Let AddNumber(ByVal Value As String)
   Text1(indice).Text = Value
End Property

Public Sub CargarComboUno(ByVal Data As ADODB.Recordset)
   cmbAddExample(indice).Clear

   Data.Open "SELECT idTipo, tipo FROM tipo_Numero", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
   Do While Not Data.EOF
       cmbAddExample(indice).AddItem Data!tipo
       cmbAddExample(indice).ItemData(cmbAddExample(indice).NewIndex) = Data!idTipo
       Data.MoveNext
   Loop
End Sub

Private Sub IniciarConexion()
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cnn
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;driver={SQL Server};server=database;uid=database;pwd=database;database=database;"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_Initialize()
    Call IniciarConexion
End Sub
```

My interface (form):

[image]

The Añadir `Button` or Add `Button` serves to copy the `UserControl` data to the `PictureBox`, I leave a descriptive `GIF`:

[image]

Code to Añadir `Button` or Add `Button`:

```
Private Sub btnAñadir_Click()
   Set rs = New Recordset
   rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer

   indice = indice + 1

   Load uc1(indice)
   Set uc1(indice).Container = Picture1
   uc1(indice).Visible = True
   uc1(indice).Top = IIf(indice = 1, 0, uc1(indice - 1).Top + uc1(indice - 1).Height + 20)

   uc1(indice).CargarComboUno rs

   uc1(indice).AddNumber = uc1(0).AddNumber
   uc1(0).AddNumber = ""

   uc1(indice).AddType = uc1(0).AddType
   uc1(0).AddType = ""

   Picture1.Visible = True

   If indice = 3 Then
   Me.btnAñadir.Enabled = False
   End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that I cannot save the values ​​because the following error comes up: R`un-time error'381 ': invalid property array index` when i press Guardar `Button` or Save `Button`.

[image]

In this line:

[image]

```
AddTypeID = cmbAddExample(indice).ItemData(cmbAddExample(indice).ListIndex)
```

Code to Guardar `Button` or Save `Button`:

```
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim id As String
Dim sel As Integer

Call IniciarConexion

Dim CM As ADODB.Command

For i = 0 To indice
    id = uc1(i).AddTypeID
    sel = uc1(i).AddNumber

Set CM = New ADODB.Command
Set CM.ActiveConnection = cnn
    CM.CommandType = adCmdText
    CM.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ejemplodOS(combo,nombre) VALUES (?,?)"
    CM.Parameters.Append CM.CreateParameter("@cmb", adInteger, , , id)
    CM.Parameters.Append CM.CreateParameter("@txt", adInteger, , , sel)
    CM.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
Next
End Sub
```

So, any sugerence? can anyone help me to solve this problem?

[image]
[image]

This is with the line `AddTypeID = 1`

Comment: This isn't a `sql server` issue, this is how you are passing the value to the command. I think you are trying to pass the whole combo box list to a single value. Try getting just the `selected index value` and passing it to the `Insert` statement.

Comment: Can you show me an example? @WEI_DBA

Comment: To get the text, `cmbAddExample(indice).Text`, to get the index value, `cmbAddExample(indice).Value`. See if that works for you. If it doesn't see if there is a `cmbAddExample(indice).SelectedIndex` property

Comment: There is no Value or SelectedIndex in vb6 for ComboBox @WEI_DBA

Comment: try without the `(indice)`, `cmbAddExample.SelectedIndex`

Comment: No, SelectedInden doesn't exist in VB6

Comment: I'm at a loss right now... When you type do you get the intellisense of what's available for properties on the combo box?

Comment: The error message is telling you either `indice` is invalid or `ListIndex` is invalid.  Since this code is inside the UserControl the combo should not have an indice.  Also, you need to guard against ListIndex being -1.  So perhaps the line should be `AddTypeID = cmbAddExample.ItemData(cmbAddExample.ListIndex)`.  Add additional code to make sure ListIndex is valid.

Comment: No, this line `AddTypeID = cmbAddExample.ItemData(cmbAddExample.ListIndex)` doesn't work either it shows me the same error: `error'381 ': invalid property array index` @BrianMStafford

Comment: Yeah, but none of those properties exist @WEI_DBA

Comment: Add additional code to make sure ListIndex is valid.

Comment: What would be the additional code I should add? @BrianMStafford

Comment: Try `If cmbAddExample.ListIndex >= 0 Then`.

Comment: Well, the following happened: I saved the value without error but the value that was saved has been one less. That is, I selected the value 1 of the ComboBox and it saved me a 0. I selected the value 2 of the combobox and it saved the 1. @BrianMStafford

Comment: Set a break point and step through your code to figure out what is happening.

Comment: I don't have idea how to solve this problem but thank you for help me @BrianMStafford

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are designing, coding, and debugging an API for the UserControl.  This API gives you access to whatever the UserControl contains whether the contents of a control, a calculation or anything else.  All your code should include error handling and other defensive coding techniques.  Make it hard for your code to fail.

When retrieving the ID you need to add some defensive code:

```
Public Property Get AddTypeID() As Integer
   If cmbAddType.ListIndex >= 0 Then
      AddTypeID = cmbAddType.ItemData(cmbAddType.ListIndex)
   Else
      AddTypeID = -1
   End If
End Property
```

Now the code will not fail.  But how about the front-end logic?  What should happen when the ID is -1?  Again, this is up to you as the designer.  But perhaps something like this:

```
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim id As Integer
   Dim sel As String
   Dim CM As ADODB.Command

   For i = 0 To indice
      id = uc1(i).AddTypeID
      sel = uc1(i).AddType

      If id > 0 Then
         Set CM = New ADODB.Command
         Set CM.ActiveConnection = cnn
         CM.CommandType = adCmdText
         CM.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ejemplodOS(combo,nombre) VALUES (?,?)"
         CM.Parameters.Append CM.CreateParameter("@cmb", adInteger, , , id)
         CM.Parameters.Append CM.CreateParameter("@txt", adInteger, , , sel)
         CM.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
      Else
         MsgBox "Respond as you want for an invalid id"
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not the problem. First that `AddTypeID = -1` save data of the ComboBox in -1 when i press AddButton to add more fields. But if i edit the value -1 for 1 values are save in 1. So, when i press the button Add and i add 3 ComboBox with the line `AddTypeID = 1` i select "celular" where id is 1 in two combos and two combos in "fijo" where id is 2 and i press button save this save the next values: 1-1-1-2 when would values are 1-1-2-2. I added a gif to show you

Comment: In looking at your code, the Insert statement is putting `AddNumber` into both columns of your table and you are not even using the ID.  Was that your intent?

Comment: The first data to be saved is the selected value of the ComboBox. That is, if "Celular" is selected, the id to be saved is 1. If "Fijo" is selected, the id to be saved is 2. And i'm sorry, in the copy paste i write addnumber in both columns